# Can Auto Layout work only for one particular screen?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

Here is the thing: I got a task to update current iOS App, which is quite old. All UI is made in xib's or frames, there are no constraints.

I have remade one screen totally on constraints, but nothing really happened. The app still looks stretched on iPhone 6/6+.

So what should I do to make adaptive UI work?

Comment: If your app is getting scaled on 6/6+ then you probably need to add properly sized launch images or a launch storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can, just turn on autolayout in the inspector in the right panel:

[image]

Comment: It was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

Your app may be auto-scaled by OS system. You should add LaunchScreen for it to support iPhone 4.7, iPhone 5.5 inch
http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/